# toastr (jquery) must only show once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please help me in limiting the appearance of a toastr. The given situation is that when I log in the system a welcome toastr will appear only once at the home screen and would not appear again in the whole session until I log out.

Here's my toastr code

```
setTimeout(function() {
           toastr.options = {
              "closeButton": true,
              "debug": false,
              "progressBar": true,
              "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
              "onclick": null,
              "showDuration": "500",
              "hideDuration": "1000",
              "timeOut": "5000",
              "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
              "showEasing": "linear",
              "hideEasing": "linear",
              "showMethod": "fadeIn",
              "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
            };
            toastr.success("Welcome Admin", "Smartcomp Solutions Inc.");
        },1000);
```

Comment: use some flag to check if it is set or not.if not then set otherwise leave it.

Comment: @SuchitKumar
im new to jquery, can you show me how to do it?

Comment: try the answer posted....

Comment: @Mikael1, Do you find out the answer to this? I have the same problem. HAHA

Answer (score 6):

use `"preventDuplicates": true,` in options

[Reference](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/k26ztyjh/)

Comment: it doesnt work, what i wanted was to only display the toastr once as a welcome notification..

Comment: if you want to display it only once use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and another way is to  call toastr without `setTimeout` and `setInterval`  in `document.ready`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show for only once try this:

```js
 toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
  "preventDuplicates": true,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
var flag=false;
setInterval(function() {
    if(!flag){
        flag=true;//store this to compare later
toastr.success("Welcome Admin", "Smartcomp Solutions Inc.");
    } },1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/build/toastr.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
```

Comment: still doesnt work, everytime i reload the page it runs the toastr,

Comment: then write is part in a function and call it only when login is successful ,in that case you don't need to do any thing else.