# Toastr only display one message at a time

Tags: laravel-5, toastr

My question is simple, yet still hard to do... I want to be able to only display one (1) message at a time using toastr.js

I have tried the following options already:

```
"maxOpened": 1,
"limit":1
```

None of those work and result in this:

[image: result]

How can I achieve that when there is a new message, the older one closes and displays the new message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310210/toastr-jquery-must-only-show-once

Comment: I have seen that topic too, but that didn't fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
toastr.options.preventDuplicates = true;
```